# Sending invitation email to auto confirmed users with AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

My desired scenario is this:

1. User is added to user pool with AWS Amplify.
2. User's email is auto verified with presignup trigger.
3. User is auto confirmed with presignup trigger.
4. User receives an invitation email from Cognito.

My problem is with the invitation email. It is not sent. Everything else prior to that is working.
I tried without auto-verify and auto-confirm and then the confirmation code is sent by email just fine.

How can I fix this issue? Is there some issue that the email isn't sent if users are auto confirmed?

Answer (score 2):

1. The invitation email is created only when you created a user as admin. if you are using the `Auth.signUp()` function, Cognito will not send an invitation email. please share your code if it is possible.
2. Please make sure that the email domain is verified (in case you are using sandbox).
   How to verify email address: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-email-addresses.html